# Calling MySQL stored procedure in ROR 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, mysql-5.5

There are few example out there but non of them are very clarified (or on old version).

I want to call MySQL procedure and check the return status (in rails `4.2`). The most common method I saw is to call `result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("call example_proc()")`, but in some places people wrote there is prepared method `result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_procedure("Stored Procedure Name", arg1, arg2)` (however it didn't compiled).

So what is the correct way to call and get the status for MySQL procedure?

Edit:

And how to send parameters safly, where the first parameter is integer, second string and third boolean?

Comment: In general, you should be able to call stored procedures in a regular `where` or `select` method for a given model: YourModel.where("YOUR_PROC(?, ?)", var1, var2) Isn't it easier? Or you have some addition requirements?

Comment: As you can see you all have different methods. If the `execute_procedure` has been deprecated I guess because of something (better approach/new method). Bottom line I want the most correct approach with procedure validation afterwards (for warnings and errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 4 `ActiveRecord::Base` doesn't support `execute_procedure` method, though `result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection` still works. ie

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("call example_proc('#{arg1}','#{arg2}')")
```

Comment: Although its working, I'm not sure its safe. First if one of the args contains `'` the procedure get broken. Second what if one of the args is `text'); delete from tags;` - How to send safly this parameters (where the first is integer, second string and third boolean)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Vishnu approach below

or

You can also try

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connections.exec_query("call example_proc('#{arg1}','#{arg2}')")
```

[here is the document](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_query)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be able to call stored procedures in a regular `where` or `select` method for a given model:

```
YourModel.where("YOUR_PROC(?, ?)", var1, var2)
```

As for your comment "Bottom line I want the most correct approach with procedure validation afterwards (for warnings and errors)", I guess it always depends on what you actually want to implement and how readable you want your code to be.

For example, if you want to return rows of YourModel attributes, then it probably would be better if you use the above statement with `where` method. On the other hand, if you write some sql adapter then you might want to go down to the ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute level.

BTW, there is something about stored proc performance that should be mentioned here. In several databases, database does stored proc optimization on the first run of the stored proc. However, the parameters that you pass to that first run might **not** be those that will be running on it more frequently later on. As a result, your stored-proc might be auto-optimized in a "none-optimal" way for your case. It may or may not happen this way, but it is something that you should consider while using stored procs with dynamic params.

Comment: The bind variable was design to handle that. As for the validation part - since it's a procedure(not returning a value) the only validation is: Pass/Fail/Warning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have tried many other solutions and got some or other errors mostly "out of sync" or "closed connection" errors. These errors occur every SECOND time you try to execute the queries. We need to workaround like the connection is new every time to overcome this. Here is my solution that didn't throw any errors.

```
#checkout a connection for Model
conn = ModelName.connection_pool.checkout

#use the new connection to execute the query
@records = conn.execute("call proc_name('params')")

#checkout the connection
ModelName.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
```

The other approaches failed for me, possibly because ActiveRecord connections are automatically handled to checkout and checking for each thread. When our method tries to checkout a connection just to execute the SP, it might conflict since there will be an active connection just when the method started.

So the idea is to manually #checkout a connection for the model instead of for thread/function from the pool and #checkin once the work is done. This worked great for me.