# Rails: Mysql2::Error: Commands out of sync

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm running a MySQL stored procedure in Rails using the Model.connection directly. All the data is inserted correctly in the DB and returned as expected but I get the following errors in my tests:

1. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now: ROLLBACK
2. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now: BEGIN

Tentative 1:

```
Model.connection.transaction do
  result = Model.connection.select_value("CALL myStoredProcedure(...);")
end
```

Tentative 2:

```
Model.connection.begin_db_transaction
result = Model.connection.select_value("CALL myStoredProcedure(...);")
Model.connection.commit_db_transaction
```

Tentative 3:

```
result = Model.connection.select_value("CALL myStoredProcedure(...);")
Model.clear_active_connections!
```

Tentative #3 resulted in "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now: BEGIN" to disappear. Still the error for the command ROLLBACK is there.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

My suspicion is that your model's connection is trying to run conflicting queries concurrently.  Rather than using `Model.connection.select_value`, try using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` :

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "CALL myStoredProcedure(...);"
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Rails v4.2 and MySQL2 v0.4.5 I found that almost any documented solution would not work. I also did not like the idea of calling clear on the active connections. So I went thru a few things. First, I tried setting the connection/query flag for multiple statements in the most supported way I could find from reading the source, a simple initializer.

```
Mysql2::Client.default_query_options[:connect_flags] |= Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS
```

And that worked fine and I could verify the flags were set, however, this did not address my issue. I was getting the out of sync error on some very basic procs. So I took my work on using the abandon_results! method and wrapped it up into a method that looks similar to the work I have done in the SQL Server adapter.

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter.class_eval do
  def execute_procedure(proc_name, *variables)
    vars = variables.map{ |v| quote(v) }.join(', ')
    response = execute "CALL #{proc_name}(#{vars})", 'Execute Procedure'
    response.each
  ensure
    raw_connection.abandon_results!
  end
end
```

Now with this in place, it was easy to execute the proc/function and get basic results.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_procedure :appsptest, 'arg1'
```

Comment: Tested in Rails 5.2.3 with mysql2 gem 0.4.10 and it works perfectly ! Thanks so much, should be the validated answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
#checkout a connection for Model
conn = ModelName.connection_pool.checkout

#use the new connection to execute the query
@records = conn.execute("call procedure('params')")

#checkout the connection
ModelName.connection_pool.checkin(conn)
```

[Here is the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940268/calling-mysql-stored-procedure-in-ror-4/31940764#31940764).